# mongoose keep count of document reference

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Say I have two models Movie and Actor

I have setup a virtual:

```
actorSchema.virtual('movies', {
    ref: 'Movie',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'actors'
})
```

And all movies document include a actors field which is a array of actor objectId.

Now if I want the count of all the movies with actor Tom Cruise, I would do:

```
Movie.countDocuments({'actor': actor_objectId})
```

of course this gets the job done, but this query has to scan the entire collection. A better approach would be to keep count on the actor document of the amount of movies that reference Tom Cruise.

example:

```
name: Tom Cruise;
movies: 10;
Height: 1.7m
```

But how to do something like this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not create the `movie_count` field in your Actor schema and increment it whenever a new movie is added that matches a given actor?

Comment: yeah this is what I am gonna do.